# Where did julien go?

Tags: discussion, specific-user

I noticed that @julien wasn't around and he doesn't turn up in search.  Did he delete his account? That would be a pity if he did.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Ron: I was just taking a break. See you around.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By using a clever Google search, I was able to find that julien only changed his user name, to reference a former Manchester United player.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a relief.

Comment: I totally agree with you.

Comment: Yup. Many people here have addressed a comment @-pinged at him. Search for those, and check which username replies (or occurs in the intersection of those threads). IOW take advantage of the fact that while his username got replaced everywhere, the pings directed at him stayed.

Comment: i.e. google "site:math.stackexchange.com @julien"

Comment: And shortly after the name change, stopped logging in to his account; last log in was August 9. :(

Comment: @user Sounds like cleaning up google search before requesting an account deletion. Hopefully not, it's always a pity to see valuable contributors distancing from their positive past

Comment: @Tobias: I'm afraid this isn't something you can't really clean up from Google.

Comment: @Asaf Not entirely (and whoever assumes the internet can be forced to forget is truly naïve), but it should at least decrease the search rank of cached versions including your previous name - e.g. my name no longer yields results (on the first view pages) from http://gaming.stackexchange.com where I changed my username a while ago.

Comment: @Tobias: But I didn't just search for "julien site:math.stackexchange.com", I did it slightly differently so I can be sure to find a quick result.

Comment: @Asaf That's what I mean with "not entirely" - you have to know what you're looking for (e.g. the presence of @-replies to the old username and specifically on math.SE - [_oh no, someone could figure out I use the name Zommuter on gaming.SE!_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm)), but a naked name-only search will no longer reveal that strong a connection to math.SE.

Comment: @Tobias: Since julien never used his full name, I don't see how that would be an issue in the first place. Searching for "julien" on Google is unlikely to have *any* relation to MSE in the first place (without even checking, too).

Comment: Agreed, however that's what happened in some previous cases where a user changed their name and became inactive. Of course julien might also just have taken vacation and made a joke. Or wanted to bet that he could steal said MU player's google rank

Comment: Reading carefully what the name actually is in combination with somewhat recent events, it should not be hard to infer what was likely the motivation for this.

Comment: ["_Is that a "protesting" nickname? =) -- Nope. Rather self-derision._"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457612/on-sections-of-the-tangent-bundle-of-a-grassmannian#comment996951_457612)

Comment: @quid I can't really figure it out yet; what recent events did I miss?

Comment: @rbm see the most recent answer of the user in question on meta.

Comment: Elementary, my dear Watson ;)

Comment: @julien: Do you mean an elementary submodel?

Comment: In (model) theory, yes.

Comment: Not the best model for math.se policy about questions on meta which ask about "where did a user go"?  "I haven't seen them for a couple of weeks?"  "It seems they've deleted their account?", "The last they said in their profile was that they had to attend to health issues."  "What happened and/or Where are they now?, and/or how can I search for them?"  All forms of such questions are asking about matters that are none of the asker's business.  I know this question is old; but when an asker on meta today was  told essentially, "we honor privacy", they linked to this question for justification.

Answer (score 4):

I really liked Julien and always looked forward to read his answers. I too noticed that he was not answering any questions of late, however, I did not think that he would have left the site. He is too valuable a mathematician to this site.

He had been generous enough to answer or comment on some of my questions and hence I traced him through them (hope he does not delete them now!).

Although, I do not know if it is a good idea to divulge his name here if he wishes to remain anonymous for some reason.

Yeah, it would be a great loss for the community if he wishes to leave.

**EDIT:** This is just to inform that Julien seems to have come back to the site. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the (too) kind words, Vishal. See you around.